Problem with linking multiple Java source directories in Gradle project
Body:
I am working on a project that has multiple Java source directories, and I am trying to configure Gradle to compile and run Java files from these directories. My current setup includes two separate source directories, and I want Gradle to recognize and compile Java files
from both:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:32.1.2-jre'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.13.0'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.9'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.plist:dd-plist:1.26'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.0'
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(23)
    }
}

application {
    mainClass = 'test1.test1'  // path to the compiled .class file
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {       
            srcDirs = ['C:/vscode/test1/dd-plist-master/src/main/java', 'app/src/main/java']
        }
    }
}

I am trying to link two different directories for Java source files, specifically:

C:/vscode/test1/dd-plist-master/src/main/java
C:/vscode/test1/app/src/main/java

However, when I run the project, I am encountering issues. The Gradle configuration should allow both directories to be included in the source sets, but it seems there are problems with how the directories are linked or recognized.
What could be the problem with this setup, and how can I correctly configure Gradle to include both source directories for compiling and running the project?

"I am encountering issues." this is not mind reading contest. You have to describe your issues in your question.

Without more information about what's going wrong, preferably accompanied by a [mre], I'm not sure how much help we can be. That said, based on your folder structure, I wonder if you're approaching this the wrong way. Perhaps a multi-project build or even a composite build would be better suited to your use case?

If I was adding a Java source directory, I would add it using the srcDir method on SourceDirectorySet rather than re-setting the property with all directories, ie:
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {       
            srcDir('C:/vscode/test1/dd-plist-master/src/main/java')
        }
    }
}

